# SOQL Subquery Header

Tags: soql

Is there a way to not show the headers as looping into the subquery results? see below. Is there a way to not show the "lastname" header?

Thanks,
John

[image]

Comment: Hi John, where you are trying this operation ?

Comment: + What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I am trying to pass a list of my attachments (through an intermediary table) to CongaComposer. The picture above was just for illustrative purposes. I have been using the following query.                                                                           select (select id from attachments) 
from program_document__c 
where program__c= '{pv0}' LIMIT 9